# Hover animation jerks when mouse leaves (using CSS transitions and transforms)

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am using CSS transitions and transform to scale the size of the circle element in an SVG. However, when my mouse leaves the element, there seems to be a jerking motion.

```
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 50 50">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" />
    <path d="M20,31 C15.4189994,27.2225585 12.5023327,24.2225585 11.25,22 C10.2743515,20.6156479 10,19.6181623 10,18.1428571 C10,15.5113854 12.4883456,13 15,13 C17.3176009,13 18.9621484,13.8491346 20,15.5714286 C21.0382977,13.8491346 22.6828452,13 25,13 C27.5116544,13 30,15.5113854 30,18.1428571 C30,19.6181623 29.7256485,20.6156479 28.75,22 C27.497816,24.2225585 24.5811493,27.2225585 20,31 Z" />
```

CSS:

```
circle {
    fill: #EEE;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .1s ease-in-out; 
}

path {
    fill: #CCC;
}

svg:hover circle {
    transform: scale(1.15);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -ms-transform-origin: center center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/aguerrero/pen/EeXJRx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `transform-origin` *properties* inside the general rules for the `circle` *element*, that way it won't have to deal with its placement only when `:hover`:

```css
circle {
  fill: #EEE;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out; 
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .1s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center center;
}

path {
  fill: #CCC;
}

svg:hover circle {
  transform: scale(1.15);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 50 50">
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" />
  <path d="M20,31 C15.4189994,27.2225585 12.5023327,24.2225585 11.25,22 C10.2743515,20.6156479 10,19.6181623 10,18.1428571 C10,15.5113854 12.4883456,13 15,13 C17.3176009,13 18.9621484,13.8491346 20,15.5714286 C21.0382977,13.8491346 22.6828452,13 25,13 C27.5116544,13 30,15.5113854 30,18.1428571 C30,19.6181623 29.7256485,20.6156479 28.75,22 C27.497816,24.2225585 24.5811493,27.2225585 20,31 Z" />
</svg>
```